# Let $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4$ be four linearly independent vectors in $R^n$. For what value of $a$ is the set linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, independence

Let $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4$ be four linearly independent vectors in $R^n$. For what value of $a$ is the set {${u_1+4u_2, u_2+3u_3, u_3+3u_4, u_4+au_1}$}
linearly dependent?

My method for solving this question was to write the terms as a vector equation equal to 0, expand the equation, and collect like terms until I was left with an equation of the following form. The $c$ terms are scalars multiplying the vectors:

$$u_1(c_1+c_4a) +u_2(4c_1+c_2)+u_3(3c_2+c_3)+u_4(3c_3+c_4)$$

I then set the four $c$ expressions equal to zero, and solved between them to determine that $a=1/36$ makes the set linearly dependent.

What I don't understand is how setting the scalar terms equal to zero, which I believe indicates the trivial solution and thus linear independence, returns the value of $a$ that will cause linear dependence.

Answer (score 1):

The two sets differ by the application $\begin{pmatrix}1&4&0&0\\0&1&3&0\\0&0&1&3\\a&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.  The linear independence of the first set implies independence of the second precisely when the transformation is invertible, or, when the determinant is nonzero.  We get $\rm{det}=1-a(4)(3)(3)=1-36a=0$ when $a=1/36$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine this more closely then. You wish to test the linear independence of these four vectors. They are linearly independent if the *only* solution for $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4$ to the following equation:
$$c_1(u_1+4u_2) + c_2(u_2+3u_3) + c_3(u_3+3u_4) + c_4(u_4+au_1) = 0 \tag{1}$$
is $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = c_4$. Otherwise the set is linearly dependent. As you note, $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$(c_1+c_4a)u_1 +(4c_1+c_2)u_2+(3c_2+c_3)u_3+(3c_3+c_4)u_4 = 0. \tag{2}$$
As $u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4$ are assumed to be linearly independent, we can conclude from this that
$$c_1 + c_4 a = 4c_1 + c_2 = 3c_2 + c_3 = 3c_3 + c_4 = 0. \tag{3}$$
Note also the converse holds true too. If $(3)$ holds, then so does $(2)$ rather trivially. So, in total, we have $(1) \iff (2) \iff (3)$. The linear independence of our set is equivalent to the system of equations in $(3)$ having only the solution $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = c_4 = 0$; if there are non-trivial solutions to $(3)$, then there are non-trivial solutions to $(1)$, and if there are no non-trivial solutions to $(3)$, then the same can be said of $(1)$.

Note that now we have removed all mention of $u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4$. This is a question purely in terms of systems of linear equations now.

Next comes the solving. Rearranging (ready for substitution), we get
\begin{align*}
c_1 &= -c_4 a \\
c_2 &= -4c_1 \\
c_3 &= -3c_2 \\
c_4 &= -3c_3.
\end{align*}
Then, performing the substitutions:
$$c_4 = -3c_3 = -3(-3c_2) = 9(-4c_1) = -36(-c_4a) = 36ac_4,$$
or, rearranging,
$$(36a - 1)c_4 = 0.$$
Now, let's consider two possibilities here: either $36a - 1 = 0$ or not. If $36a - 1 \neq 0$, then we may divide both sides by $36a - 1$ (we can divide by any non-zero number), and hence the above equation implies $c_4 = 0$. From here, we may back substitute into our system to discover $c_1 = 0$, hence $c_2 = 0$, and finally $c_3 = 0$. That is, the only solution when $36a - 1 \neq 0$ is $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = c_4 = 0$. Hence this is the only solution for $(1)$ as well, and so our vectors are linearly independent if $36a - 1 \neq 0$.

Otherwise, if $36a - 1 = 0$, i.e. if $a = 1/36$, then we suddenly get a free variable $c_4$. Let's choose a non-zero value for $c_4$, e.g. $c_4 = 1$. Then $c_1 = -c_4a = -1/36$, $c_2 = -4c_1 = 1/9$, $c_3 = -3c_2 = -1/3$, and we can verify that these values then also satisfy $c_4 = -3c_3$ as well. Thus, we have a non-trivial solution
$$(c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4) = (-1/36, 1/9, -1/3, 1),$$
which implies that $(1)$ is linearly dependent.

I hope that clarifies things.